# toggle class on click with javascript on 2 ways, which is correct?

Tags: javascript, dom

Are any of these versions correct? I would like the icon to change after clicking the menu. in Javascript these are my beginnings and I don't know what is right

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
menu.onclick = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('fa-times');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
};
```

or this

```
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');
menu.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  menu.classList.toggle('fa-times');
  navbar.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but there are several differences between `onclick` and `addEventListener`.

1. `addEventListener` can add multiple events to a particular element.
   `onclick` can add only a single event to an element. It is basically a
   property, so gets overwritten.
2. `addEventListener` can take a third argument that can control the
   event propagation. Event propagation cannot be controlled by `onclick`.
3. `addEventListener` does not work in older versions of Internet
   explorer, which uses attachEvent instead. `onclick` works in all browsers.